# Tomcat7 to Tomcat8 performance degraded (Almost 50%)

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat8

I did the app server upgrade from tomcat7 to tomcat8 on our production env. Hardware configuration are exactly same as old env.

I am seeing avg response time increased almost 50% (from 204ms to ~450ms) I looked at our APM and I can see the JSP processing time  increased in tomcat8 app server.

Anyone out here faced this issue before? If so please share the solution.

Here am attaching tomcat7 and tomcat8 key transaction breakdown.

I see JSP processing time significantly increased on tomcat8.

Tomcat7:

[image: Tomcat7 Key transaction breakdown]

Tomcat8:
[image: Tomcat8 Key transaction breakdown]

Comment: What App did you user to monitor Tomcat and create thos lovely graphs?

Comment: Newrelic APM :)

Answer (score 2):

Finally I figured it out: Apache Tomcat8 Documentation helped me to identify the issue.

> Unified Expression Language 3.0 added support for referencing static fields and methods. Supporting this feature in JSPs required changing the javax.servlet.jsp.el.ScopedAttributeELResolver implementation so that it also checked identifiers to see if they were names of imported classes or fields. In some circumstances, this change triggers significant slow down. This affects identifiers that may refer to a page, request, session or application scoped variable or may be undefined. When undefined, it takes significantly longer to resolve the identifier since it is now also checked to see if it is an imported class or field. To avoid this slow down, code such as:
>
> ${undefined}
>
> should be replaced with:
>
> ${requestScope.undefined}
>
> or similar, using the appropriate scope for where the variable is
>   defined.

Here is the full documentation: https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-8.html#JavaServer_Pages_2.3

For now I degraded tomcat to version 7 and started working with developers to fix the issue, Hopefully will upgrade back to tomcat8 by next month!